# Titles of the articles published by Friedrich, Knipping, and Laue in 1913 concerning the discovery of x-ray diffraction

Tags: specific-reference

I am trying to find references to the revolutionary articles published by Friedrich, Knipping, and Laue in 1913, with their original titles, but I seem unable to do so. Can anyone here provide the references?

If I understand this correctly, Laue published an article alone on the theoretical part concerning how x-rays are diffracted by crystals, and Friedrich & Knipping published their own article about the experimental setup. Is this correct?

Comment: Footnote 1 in [this PDF](http://amhistory.si.edu/docs/Forman_Diffract_Xrays_Xtals.pdf) might be able to lead someone (with better library access than me) to the articles and their titles.